# How do UBOs/SSBOs differ from Vulkan's shader memory bindings?

Tags: opengl, vulkan

In the [article on Imagination's website](http://blog.imgtec.com/powervr/trying-out-the-new-vulkan-graphics-api-on-powervr-gpus), I've read the following paragraph:

> For example, there are no `glUniform*()` equivalent entry points in Vulkan; instead, writing to GPU memory is the only way to pass data to shaders.
>
> When you call `glUniform*()`, the OpenGL ES driver typically needs to allocate a driver managed buffer and copy data to it, the management of which incurs CPU overhead. In Vulkan, you simply map the memory address and write to that memory location directly.

Is there any difference between that and using Uniform Buffers? They are also allocated explicitely and can carry arbitrary data. Since Uniform Buffers are quite limited in size, perhaps [Shader Storage Buffers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) are a better analogy.

Comment: openGL drivers are free to create a uniform buffer containing all the uniforms not already in a buffer and reference that in glUniform calls; Vulkan seems to make that explicit

Comment: Sounds very similar to uniform buffers.  I suppose we'll find out on the 5th when Valve do their GDC talk.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From what I understand, this is not `glUniform*()` specific: `glUniform*()` is merely an example used by the author of the article to illustrate the way Vulkan works with regards to communication between the host and the GPU.

> When you call `glUniform*()`, the OpenGL ES driver typically needs to allocate a driver managed buffer and copy data to it, the management of which incurs CPU overhead.

In this scenario, when a user calls `glUniform*()` with some data, that data is first copied to a buffer owned by the OpenGL implementation. This buffer is probably pinned, and can then be used by the driver to transfer the data through DMA to the device. That's two steps:

1. Copy user data to driver buffer;
2. Transfer buffer contents to GPU through DMA.

> In Vulkan, you simply map the memory address and write to that memory location directly.

In this scenario, there is *no intermediate copy* of the user data. You ask Vulkan to map a region into the host's virtual address space, which you directly write to. The data gets to the device through DMA in a completely transparent way for the user.

From a performance standpoint, the benefits are obvious: zero copy. It also means the Vulkan implementation can be simpler, as it does not need to manage an intermediate buffer.

As the specs have not been released yet, here's a fictitious example of what it could look like:

```
// Assume Lights is some kind of handle to your buffer/data
float4* lights = vkMap(Lights);

for (int i = 0; i < light_count; ++i) {
    // Goes directly to the device
    lights[i] = make_light(/* stuff */);
}

vkUnmap(lights);
```

Comment: ... and presumably you pass a "pointer" to your shader instead of assigning layout slots and binding to those?

Comment: @Robinson: That seems to be the direction the API's been headed for quite some time now. Things like validation that occur when you bind objects are undesirable performance wise and Mantle, Vulkan, Metal, DX12, etc. try to do away with all that stuff by letting you instead shoot yourself in the foot ;) Object binding also sort of typecasts resources into being one thing or another, which as we saw with the introduction of texture views, is not always necessary. The new paradigm is just to treat resources as arbitrary memory and let the application developer figure out how to make sense of it.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman It should be pointed out that this does not necessarily mean a loss in type safety; at least on higher levels. Of course if you're using Vulkan from C or C++ directly you're able to shoot yourself in your foot all day. But most graphics applications have their own abstraction layer anyway (and the OpenGL drivers' layers just add bloat) and given these domain specific abstraction layers things become nice to work with again.

Comment: @datenwolf: I wasn't so much referring to a loss in type safety as much as a loss in state validation. Whereas in GL you get immediate feedback if you're trying to use a resource in an inconsistent state, that's not the case in the new wave of lower-level APIs. They will let you invoke undefined behavior even easier than GL does. Vulkan will work well if you fit it into an engine that already implements its own validation and command scheduling; that's kind of its point, not to duplicate that work.

Comment: Author here, binding some memory to a slot is a command in vulkan: vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(). Probably a pointer behind the scenes though.

Comment: The statement is not accurate. It's just one of many ways to copy buffer. Making everything visible to host might lead to slow performance.